# Draw bitmap in different activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, bitmap

So my app should capture image with intent then draw that image in different activity, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:
Main activity:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "pic.jpg");
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullActivity.class);
        startActivity(k);
    }
}
```

Second activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
     iv.setImageBitmap(bp);
}
```

Can someone help me and show where the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the second Activity? what result do you expect?

Comment: onActivityResult should use in same activity. You can pass bitmap or photo as a string in next activity using Intent.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani how do you write camera intent output to string?

Comment: I think you are confusing Intent extras with activity result

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `Uri` as a string with the `Intent` in your `MainActivity`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullActivity.class);
        k.putExtra("uri", imageUri.toString());
        startActivity(k);
    }
}
```

Then get the string in your `FullActivity` and parse it to a `Uri`, then use that to set your `ImageView`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    String uriString = getIntent().getStringExtra("uri");
    Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(uriString);
    // you may also need to call imageView.setImageURI(null); here
    // or get the bitmap first to use imageView.setImageBitmap();
    imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

> Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode
>   you started it with, the resultCode it returned, and any additional
>   data from it

Your `onActivityResult` never get called when starting `Second activity`

Try send the `uri` you receive in `Main activity` in `Bundle`

```
 Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActiviy.class);
 intent.putExtra("mUri", imageUri.toString());
```

And you can get this uri on `SecondActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String uri= getIntent().getStringExtra("mUri");
    Uri imageUri= Uri.parse(uri);
    Bitmap bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Global Declaration<br>    

        private Uri fileUri;
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO = 101;

        // Click for capture Image

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO); // create a file to save the image
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO);



        @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                try {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO) {
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        String PATH = fileUri.getPath();

                        Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullActivity.class);
                        k.putExtra("KEY_FOR_PATH, PATH);
                        startActivity(k);


                    }
                }
            }
        }


        // In FullActivity

        String pathOfFile = getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_FOR_PATH");
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathOfFile);

        //Now set myBitmap in ImageView
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)
```

// Add this method

```
private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "YOUR IMAGE FOLDER");
        if(imagesFolder != null && !imagesFolder.exists()) {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        int photonum = AppTypeDetails.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getImageName();
        AppTypeDetails.getInstance(ReportTab.this).setImageName(++photonum);
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, String.format("image%08d.jpeg", photonum));
        return Uri.fromFile(image);
    }
```

Comment: It says that method fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO); not accessible or undefined, any way to fix it?

Comment: Have you declared that var global?